# Callback in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in which eslint suggests: "Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state." Tell me, how do I need to rewrite the code to update the state of the component in setState?

I tried to pass the function to the second argument in setState, but I get an error and I don’t know if this is the right approach.

State:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    minutes: '24',
    seconds: '59',
    disabled: false,
  };
}
```

componentDidMount and setState:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const prevMinutes = localStorage.getItem('minutes');
  const prevSeconds = localStorage.getItem('seconds');

  this.setState({
    minutes: +prevMinutes !== 0 ? +prevMinutes : this.state.minutes, // warning here
    seconds: +prevSeconds !== 0 ? +prevSeconds : this.state.seconds, // and here
  });
}
```

Now the code is working correctly, it is logical, but I would like to understand the correct approach when creating such structures.

P.S. I know about destructuring, I will do this after I understand why I need to do a callback and how to do it correctly.

Comment: `setState((oldState) => changes)`. Read the guidance in the rule docs: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-access-state-in-setstate.md

Comment: You should actually use the second method of using `setstate` i.e, by sending in a function which receives previous state as the parameter and use that object instead of directly referencing `this.state`

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the link! Through VS Code, it did not open :)

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt thanks for the explanation, now it is much clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not second argument, it is still first argument (called updater) but you replace object by function like this:

```js
this.setState(prev => ({
  minutes: +prevMinutes !== 0 ? +prevMinutes : prev.minutes,
  seconds: +prevSeconds !== 0 ? +prevSeconds : prev.seconds,
}));
```

according to:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

second argument is just callback which is called after state is changed.